# can't install mysql-connector on Python 3.5.3 with pip3

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have successfully installed mysql-connector using 'pip install mysql-connector', however it installs to the Mac OSX standard version of Python (2.7).

I need it installed to my latest version of Python (3.5.3).

When I use 'pip3 install mysql-connector' or 'pip3 install --allow-external mysql-connector mysql-connector' I get the following errors:

```
Error 1:
Failed building wheel for mysql-connector

Error 2:
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ch/vzgxn0n119zggbgnb0_vg5400000gn/T/pip-build-po0zonwm/mysql-connector/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/ch/vzgxn0n119zggbgnb0_vg5400000gn/T/pip-q6b3vmy3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ch/vzgxn0n119zggbgnb0_vg5400000gn/T/pip-build-po0zonwm/mysql-connector/
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? I don't want to have to switch back to Python 2.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the thing:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```